# div when animated using jQuery, pushes all other divs down

Tags: jquery, css

All I want to do is have a div move down the page to a certain position, now the animation works but it also moves all the other divs down as well, how can I fix this?

The div in html code

```
   <div id = "Sidepanel" style="background:#98bf21;height:0px;width:150px;top:0px;opacity:0;position:relative;left:5px"></div>
```

The jQuery used

```
$("#Sidepanel").animate({height:560,top:1010,opacity:1},"slow");
```

The div that surrounds all the content on the website

```
#wrapper {
    padding: 0;
    background: url(images/main-image-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;}
```

Comment: You need to post your code as we can't see it from over here, you're too far away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it absolute position to take it out of the document flow, then use `top` to move it around (or ideally CSS transforms where possible).

Comment: Yes, like this: `$('#myDiv').css({position:'absolute',top:'1000px'}); $('#myDiv').css('position','relative');`, assuming 1000px is where you would want the element.

Comment: Animating a translate transform sounds like the best idea to me.